# delegate pass to other ViewController

Tags: swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I want to pass a delegate like `var delegate: Diary?`from my HeaterViewController to my DetailViewController to get the core data attributes of it. So I have set the delegate in func didselectItem `view.delegate = diarys`but it don´t run I have no segue to pass the data between the view controllers. So the question was how I can pass the delegate between the view controllers to get the title from the core data entry. 
The other thing is I want to get access to the func from the headerviewcontroller from a other viewcontroller. I have tried with

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiaryController") as! DiaryController
    vc.loadDiarys()
```

but it don´t run so I need the func from the DiaryController (loadDiarys) in this viewcontroller. I have no segue to use.

Code from DetailViewController:

```
var delegate: Diary?

AddTitle.text = delegate.title
```

Code from HeaderViewController:

```
var diary = [Diary] () {
    didSet {
        self.DiaryCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
var mgdContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

load new Entry:

```
func loadDiarys () {
    let loadRequest: NSFetchRequest<Diary> = Diary.fetchRequest()
    diary = try! mgdContext.fetch(loadRequest as!     NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! [Diary]
    print("loadD")
}
```

hand over delegate to other ViewController (DetailDiaryController)

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let diarys = diary[indexPath.row]

        let view = DetailDiaryController.instantiateFromNib()

        view.delegate = diarys





        let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!
        let modal = PathDynamicModalPan()
        modal.showMagnitude = 200.0
        modal.closeMagnitude = 130.0
        view.closeButtonHandler = {[weak modal] in
            modal?.closeWithLeansRandom()
            return
        }
        view.bottomButtonHandler = {[weak modal] in
            modal?.closeWithLeansRandom()
            return
        }
        modal.show(modalView: view, inView: window!)

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand from your question what it is that's not working.

Comment: the data what I will send to the other view controllers don´t come on. So I get no data from the delegate and the func what I set don´t run.